# Animation for all buttons

Tags: android, animation

I am trying to create an animation that I can use for different buttons on my app. The animation is basically a circle that expands filling the entire screen when a button is pressed.

For that purpose I have created my animation XML file like this:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="20.0"
        android:toYScale="20.0"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%">

    </scale>
</set>
```

I am applying this animation to an `ImageView`, and in order to use the animation on every button I have placed the entire layout within a `FrameLayout` and when I want to use the animation, place change the location of the `ImageView` to be animated and I use the `onTouchListener` for the button that I need to animate like this:

```
imbt_buttonOn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()){
                    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
                        imvw_expand.setX(imbt_buttonOn.getX());
                        imvw_expand.setY(imbt_buttonOn.getY());
                        imvw_expand.startAnimation(animation);
                        break;
                    case (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):
                        imvw_expand.clearAnimation();
                        imvw_expand.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        animationCanceled = true;
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

The problem: the imageView that has to be animated appears in the desired position and also expands....but it also moves down out of the screen.

Any help would be appreciated or any better way to do a re-usable expanding circle animation.

Comment: Interesting upvote 5 seconds after question was posted..

Comment: yeah saw that...weird

Comment: Hahaha because I am also trying this. I have upvote this question after reading first two lines

Comment: good to know that im not alone on that :)

Comment: Ya let me know if you find any solution @codeKiller

Comment: why don't you use 'ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal' from support library

Comment: I have been playing with that but I do not get to achieve the desired effect of filling the entire screen whatever the position of the button clicked, it is a bit hard in my opinion, that is why i went for this other type of animation

Comment: Have you tried with objectAnimator. As I have tried I can see that it behaves a bit differently than animation from xml.   


                        final AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
                        animatorSet.playTogether(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, View.SCALE_X, 1f, 20f),
                                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, View.SCALE_Y, 1f, 20f));
                        animatorSet.setDuration(2000);
                        animatorSet.start();

Comment: `but it also moves down out of the screen` can you post a screenshot of that? And also, what you expect to happen.